# Custom element not picking up attributes

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom, custom-element

I am trying to have a look at custom elements and how they work and while the examples on MDN work fine I'm seemingly unable to replicate them myself.

The MDN article is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements).

[This](https://mdn.github.io/web-components-examples/popup-info-box-external-stylesheet/) is a working example from MDN.

My problem is that I can't ever seem to pass attributes into my component, they always come out as null instead of passing over the value of the parameter.

My JS is (test.js)

```js
  class PopUpInfo extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      // Always call super first in constructor
      super();
  
      // Create a shadow root
      const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
  
      // Create spans
      const wrapper = document.createElement('span');
      const info = document.createElement('span');
 
      // Take attribute content and put it inside the info span
      const text = this.getAttribute('foo'); // <-- this always returns null
      info.textContent = `(${text})`;

      shadow.appendChild(wrapper);
      wrapper.appendChild(info);
    }
  }
  
  // Define the new element
  customElements.define('popup-info', PopUpInfo);
```

And my Html:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <hr>

        <popup-info foo="Hello World"></popup-info> 

        <hr>

    </body>
</html>
```

What I'm expecting to see on screen is the text

> (Hello World)

but all I ever see is

> (null)

When I debug I can see that `this.attributes` has a length of 0 so it's not being passed in.

Has anyone seen this before when creating custom elements?

Comment: You can't access DOM data in the ``constructor``, only in (or after) the ``connectedCallback`` see: https://andyogo.github.io/custom-element-reactions-diagram/

Comment: Ah... this makes sense. Really appreciate the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your example seems to run fine when I try to run it here in a snippet, I still want to make a suggestion to improve it.

Use the `observedAttributes` static getter to define a list of attributes which the component should keep an eye on. When the value of an attribute has been changed and the name of the attribute is in the list, then `attributeChangedCallback` callback is called. In there you can assert logic on what to do whenever you attribute value has been changed.

In this case you could build your string that you desire. This also has the side effect that whenever the attribute value is changed again, the string will be updated.

```js
class PopUpInfo extends HTMLElement {

  /**
   * Observe the foo attribute for changes.
   */
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['foo'];
  }

  constructor() {
    super();

    const shadow = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });

    const wrapper = document.createElement('span');
    const info = document.createElement('span');
    wrapper.classList.add('wrapper');

    wrapper.appendChild(info);
    shadow.appendChild(wrapper);
  }
  
  /**
   * Returns the wrapper element from the shadowRoot.
   */
  get wrapper() {
    return this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.wrapper')
  }
  
  /**
   * Is called when observed attributes have a changed value.
   */
  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldValue, newValue) {
    switch(attrName) {
      case 'foo':
        this.wrapper.textContent = `(${newValue})`;
        break;
    }
  }
  
}

// Define the new element
customElements.define('popup-info', PopUpInfo);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <hr>

  <popup-info foo="Hello World"></popup-info>

  <hr>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Note that ``attributeChangedCallback`` is **also** called before the element is connected, so you *might* want to check for ``oldValue===null``. See JSFidlle: https://jsfiddle.net/CustomElementsExamples/n20bwckt/ for a trace when/what executes. But **DO** check in both FireFox and Chrome; there are differences!

Comment: Hi Danny, great additions to the answer and definitely things to keep in mind. Your jsfiddle is very insightful into the lifecycle and behavior of custom elements.

Answer (score 3):

Keep Emiel his answer as the correct one.

Just to show there are alternative and shorter notations possible:

```js
customElements.define('popup-info', class extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['foo'];
  }

  constructor() {
    const wrapper = document.createElement('span');
    super().attachShadow({mode:'open'})// both SETS and RETURNS this.shadowRoot
           .append(wrapper);
    this.wrapper = wrapper;
  }
  
  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    switch(name) {
      case 'foo':
        this.wrapper.textContent = `(${newValue})`;
        break;
    }
  }
  
});
```

```html
<popup-info 
  foo="Hello World"
  onclick="this.setAttribute('foo','Another world')"
  >
</popup-info>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a defer attribute in your script import within the HTML and it is not loading properly, thats the problem. The defer attribute allows the script to be executed after the page is parsed

```js
class PopUpInfo extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    // Always call super first in constructor
    super()

    // Create a shadow root
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })

    // Create spans
    const wrapper = document.createElement('span')
    const info = document.createElement('span')

    // Take attribute content and put it inside the info span
    const text = this.getAttribute('foo') // <-- this always returns null

    info.textContent = `(${text})`

    shadow.appendChild(wrapper)
    wrapper.appendChild(info)
  }
}

// Define the new element
customElements.define('popup-info', PopUpInfo)
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="app.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <hr />

    <popup-info foo="Hello World"></popup-info>

    <hr />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a completely wrong answer. Custom Elements can be defined at **any** time. ``defer`` is a not a solution but a hack. The other answer given is correct.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Hi, i don't really think this a hack, its just simple management of the flow of the scripts on a page. Even the [MDN example](https://mdn.github.io/web-components-examples/popup-info-box-external-stylesheet/) he shows follows the same logic wit the **defer** attribute. But i agree that if he needs a more robust implementation of a custom element, he might wanna follow the solution given in the other answer.

Comment: I'm not sure we can say it's completely wrong, the MDN pages clearly have it set up this way [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define). However I think the question is whether this is the best way of doing it? The fact that MDN examples are like this does give it some credence though.

Comment: No where on that MDN page says it to use ``defer`` for loading Script. The whole point is that Web Components can be defined/upgraded **before** or **after** usage. Setting ``defer`` **always** upgrades the Components **late** (which you most of the time don't want, because it creates FOUCs). It "solves" your original *problem*; but it is not the solution. It is like jump starting your car, then saying it has no starting problem because it runs.

Comment: I think the exact problem is that no where on the MDN page does it say to use the defer for script loading, despite the example they have clearly needing it. I've found the Google documentation to be far better now and explain things clearer. Yes, your and Emiel's answers are better and now the accepted answer.

I suspect what needs to be done is actually improvements to the MDN article.